# Sort Python list by dict key,value

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary of card ranks and values and I want to sort a list of 4 cards so that cards will be appropriately ordered based on rank AND value.

```
RANKS = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
VALUES = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 , 10, 10, 10, 10]
val_dict = dict(zip(RANKS, VALUES))


list = ["2","2","3","A"] # should sort to ["A",2,2,3]
list2 = ["10","K","J","Q"] # sort to [10,"J","Q","K"]
```

Background:
I am wanting to sort these lists in this manner in order to count runs in a cribbage hand. I use the card's ordinal values to determine if they are sequential. (I could provide that code as well if it might help to re-do that)

Comment: Should `list` (and not a good naming choice btw) be `["2", "2", "3", "A"]` ?

Comment: Just sample code, not in production.

And yes, they are strings. Will update.

Comment: Why are you mixing ranks and values in the same list

Comment: rather than value and rank, it seems to me that ranks is sufficient. However, you'll find that your list should contain only one type of object to have a simple sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your lists are consistent (i.e. `['2', '2', '3', 'A']`) and consist of elements of `RANKS`, ordering by position in `RANKS` is sufficient :

```
>>> sorted(['2', '2', '3', 'A'], key=lambda x: RANKS.index(x))
['A', '2', '2', '3']
>>> sorted(['10',"K","J","Q"], key=lambda x: RANKS.index(x))
['10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
```

### Edit

Alternatively, you can use

```
val_dict = dict(zip(RANKS, zip(VALUES, range(len(VALUES)))))
```

which create a dict that associates the RANK name with its value and its index. You can then simply sort using

```
sorted(myList, key=val_dict.get)
```

as suggested several times.

### Edit (again)

Following the same idea, but much simpler, the actual rank of a card can be put in a dict such as this one

```
{k: v for v, k in enumerate(RANKS)}
```

for faster lookup. Identically, the value can be put in another dict for fast lookup :

```
{RANKS[v]: k for v, k in enumerate(VALUES)}
```

Comment: Only drawback is that this makes the sort inefficient.

Comment: I missed the part that OP wants to sort a list of size 4. :/

Comment: So far this has worked for all of the tests I have. Surprisingly simple answer, thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You've pretty much got it, you just need to utilise the `val_dict` you define:

```
RANKS = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
VALUES = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 , 10, 10, 10, 10]
val_dict = dict(zip(RANKS, VALUES))
```

Now just add to your code above something that uses `val_dict` to look up the ranking for a value... eg:

```
mylist = ["2","2","3","A"] # should sort to ["A",2,2,3]
mylist_sorted = sorted(mylist, key=val_dict.get)
# ['A', '2', '2', '3']
```

As @Ashwini correctly points out, this won't result in the desired order as per your second example. A fairly simple way around this to keep the logic simple is to change the values:

```
VALUES = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9] , [10, 1], [10, 2], [10, 3], [10, 4]]
```

Comment: this seems incredibly complicated for such a simple task.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> VALUES = range(len(RANKS))
>>> val_dict = dict(zip(RANKS, VALUES))
>>> sorted([2,2,3,"A"], key=lambda x:val_dict[str(x)])
['A', 2, 2, 3]
>>> sorted([10,"K","J","Q"], key=lambda x:val_dict[str(x)])
[10, 'J', 'Q', 'K']
```

Comment: `VALUES` is also used for scoring, so K = 10, Q = 10, etc. I think I can utilize your answer, though, so thanks for the idea there.

Comment: @erbaker Python's sort is stable sort, for items with equal value their original order in the list will be preserved. So, you need to use different values.

Comment: this is totally overkill for simply associating the index of the rank to the rank name. in the end. `val_dict[a] == RANKS.index(a)`

Comment: Dicts provide `O(1)` lookup, `list.index` is `O(N)`. But for huge list this would scale well.